# Command line arguments and "global settings" in WPF à la Clean Code

Tags: wpf, mvvm, coding-style, command-line-arguments, application-settings

What possibilities do I have to write clean code for the following case:

```
public class App : Application
{
    protected override OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var arguments = (MyArgumentClass)CommandLineArgumentParser.Parse(e.Args);
        // and what now?
    }
}

public class ShellViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // ...
    public SubViewModel SubViewModel {get; protected set;}
}

public class SubViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // is some property which should be set depending on command line arguments
    // in the real code it is not just one property in one view model
    // but several properties in different view models
    public bool MyFlag { get; set;}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Where do I store (which class) and apply the command line arguments to the view models which needs them?
2. The same question for application settings.

My ideas:

- Store the settings in App as static property, so i could access the values easily from the view model per App.CommandLineArgumets.Flag when it's required. Problem: This would tie the view model to the actual application. In the case where this question arose, this exactly is the problem (the same problem with Properties.Settings.Default)
- Pass the CommandLineArguments object to the view and set values of the view model from the view. Problem i see in this case: I have two applications which use the same view model class (maybe it will be more soon). If I have to change the view model class or any subclass, I would need to update the code in all applications which consumes it. But maybe it is still kind of clean?
- For application settings I could also pass an instance of Propertes.Settings.Default as ApplicationSettingsBase to the view model but it feels not right, that the view model is reponsible of reading and eventually storing the settings.
- Access the command line arguments via Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() where they are needed. But this would require parsing of the command line arguments at several places in the code.

Maybe there is a better/cleaner solution for this kind of problem, or i overlooked something. I am looking for a general solution for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the arguments into the ViewModel's constructor is my recommendation. You will need to instantiate the ViewModel at some point, and the factory code is likely to have access to the command-line arguments if you store them as static variables in the app (as per your first scenario).
Most IoC containers allow you to pass command-line arguments, so if you are using IoC you should be able to achieve the results you require, while keeping your ViewModels decoupled from the application